# how to make div overflow when there're some tables in the div content

Tags: css, html, web

My html code with inline css:

```
<div id="ggicci_syntax_highlighter" style="border: solid 3px black; cursor: text; overflow-x: auto; width: 100%;">
    <table id="ggicci_outer_table" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Consolas;">
        <colgroup>
            <col style="background-color: #44F;"><!-- You can set font here -->
            <col style="background-color: #f4f4f4; width: 100%;">
        </colgroup>
        <tr>
            <td></td><!-- corner -->
            <td id="ggicci_language_text" style="font-size:25px; color: #777; font-family: Arial Black;"> <!-- header -->
                C++
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table id="ggicci_line_number" style="font-size: 14px; color: #DDD;"><!-- You can set style here -->
                    <tr>
                        <td>1:</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2:</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>3:</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>4:</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>5:</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>6:</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>7:</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>8:</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table id="ggicci_code_body" style="font-size: 14px; width: 100%;"><!-- You can set style here -->
                    <tr>
                        <td style="background: #FFF">
                            <span style="color:#FF7700; font-weight:bold;">#include</span> &lt;iostream&gt;
                        </td>                   
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span style="color:blue; font-weight:bold;">using</span> namespace std;
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="background: #FFF">
                            &nbsp;
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span style="color:blue; font-weight:bold;">int</span> main()
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="background:#FFF;">
                            {
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;std::cout &lt;&lt; <span style="color:#EB2244;">"Hello World!"</span> &lt;&lt; std::endl;<span style="color:green;">//write "Hello World!" to console............................................................</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="background: #FFF">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color:blue; font-weight:bold;">return</span> 0;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            }
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

and I can't make the content in div scroll when the text in a line in the table where the id is "ggicci_code_body" overflows. I'm new to css and now I'm designing a syntax highlighter for programming practice. So any solution? and why this can't work?
[image]

Comment: I created a jsfiddle is this you want http://jsfiddle.net/6jpH8/

Comment: @Shusl no, it does not scroll along x-axis. I want the text in the table(id = "ggicci_code_body") to scroll along x-axis when it overflows. Because this is a static html snippet and I can't modify the line numbers dynamically, so if the text overflows and goes to the next line, it would be ugly...

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/6jpH8/1/ ?

Comment: @Shusl yes, it's what i want, but why it doesn't work in my browsers(IE9, Chrome)?

Comment: @Ggicci I don't have IE9 at hand, but I did the fiddle in Chrome and it works fine. And this should be a universal solution since `nowrap` is even supported in IE8. What do you see in your browsers?

Comment: @Passerby you can copy the code and saved it in a html file, then open it in your browsers. i think the lines would never overflow. I've found a solution that if adding `nowrap` to every `td` tag, it would work. but it seems no effect to add `nowrap` to a `table`.

Comment: @Ggicci I also did that and Chrome still works fine for me. Are you sure there's no other styling that somehow affects this table? Because adding the same style to every `td` seems, well, inefficient.

Comment: @Passerby [Effect in my IE9](http://imgout.ph.126.net/9227037/2012-10-11_1817.jpg) [Effect in my Chrome](http://imgout.ph.126.net/9227038/2012-10-11_1817_001.jpg)

Comment: @Passerby and i don't know why it causes messy word in chrome

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17862/discussion-between-passerby-and-ggicci)

Answer (score 0):

Add '<!doctype html>' at the start of html file.